# K8s: How can a pod access NFS mount without restarting?

Tags: kubernetes

On a Kubernetes cluster, where a pod is already running on a node, can it access an NFS mount of the node directly?

I tried using host path on the pod, following the process below:

1. started pod with host path, and created an empty dir on the node, e.g. `/data/nfs_dir`
2. mounted NFS on node, e.g.: `mount -t nfs 10.0.1.16:/data/nfs /data/nfs_dir/`

The pod can access the NFS service mounted on the host path only after restarting, how could it directly gain access without restarting?

ps:can't use pv/pvc

Answer (score 0):

`volumes` can be `emptyDir` / `hostPath` / `nfs`

Why don't you just mount `NFS` in `pod` and use it? Here is a demo

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: podvolumenfs
  name: podvolumenfs
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: volumes1
    nfs:
      server: 10.0.1.16
      path: /data/nfs
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: podvolumehostpath
    command: ['sh','-c','sleep 5000']
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data/nfs_dir
      name: volumes1
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

via `hostPath`, which is a bit of a pain in the ass

Comment: because don't want to restart the pod.  need change nfs address dynamic.

Comment: Pods get restarted and deleted all the time, sometimes outside your control.  Changing _anything_ in a Deployment will cause you to get new Pods.  That's totally routine, and I wouldn't especially try to avoid it.